# The thread keeps running in the background after I loop an ImageView slideshow in Android?

Tags: android

```
        RefreshHandler refreshHandler = new RefreshHandler();
        class RefreshHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Level1.this.updateUI();
               }
        public void sleep(long delayMillis){
                               this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
               }
        }; 
        public void updateUI(){

        if(i<=imgid.length){
        refreshHandler.sleep(100);

        if(i<imgid.length){
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[i]);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (i>=imgid.length) {
            i = 0;
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[i]);
        }
        i++;
```

The loop works fine, the image slideshow keeps going.
When I click the back button and start a different activity the logcat keeps writing messages which tells me that the thread keeps running in the background.
How do I stop that?
I am new to programming so please don't be harsh to me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a way to know whether or not to call your RefreshHandler's sleep method (which is what is continuing the "loop".)

You can use a boolean member variable in your Activity and tie it to your Activity's onPause()/onResume() lifecycle callbacks to help you know whether or not to continue your slide show.

In addition, **you should be careful not to leak your Level1 Activity** by making your RefreshHandler static (if its an inner class) and holding onto a WeakReference to your Level1 Activity.

Have a look at this excellent article regarding the leaking Activity from a Handler problem by Alex Lockwood here:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

Try something like this:

```
public class Level1 extends Activity
{
    public static class RefreshHandler extends Handler
    {
        private WeakReference<Level1> level1Ref;

        public RefreshHandler(Level1 level1)
        {
            super();
            level1Ref = new WeakReference<Level1>(level1);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            Level1 level1 = level1Ref.get();

            if (level1 != null)
            {
                level1.updateUI();
            }
        }

        public void sleep(long delayMillis) 
        {
            this.removeMessages(0);
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
        }
    };

    private boolean slideshowRunning = false;
    private RefreshHandler refreshHandler = new RefreshHandler(this);

    public void updateUI()
    {
        if (slideshowRunning) 
        {
            // call refreshHandler.sleep
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        slideshowRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        slideshowRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Please look at the code that I added. I am lost.

Comment: Hi Michael. I have put the whole code and for now I just want to make it work. Then I'll try to understand it. Right now it's not working because obviously something is missing. Thank you for your help!!!